# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method JSite::execute() joomla installation

Tags: joomla

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method JSite::execute() joomla installation

Hi, I am trying to move the joomla file with ine server with another server, I have used Akeeba Kickstart for that purpose, but after the installation the above messege shows.

Current server 1and1.uk

Comment: Can you provide more details? Joomla version, PHP version, Apache/NGINX etc

Comment: PHP version 7.1

Comment: Joomla!  - Version 3.8.6 - Standard